# AlmaLinux 8.7 xrdp Remote Desktop Setup

Tags: rhel, vnc, remote-desktop, xrdp, alma-linux

I recently set up xrdp on my AlmaLinux 8.7 machine using the following guide: [Access AlmaLinux 8 remote desktop using Windows RDP](https://www.how2shout.com/linux/access-almalinux-8-remote-desktop-using-windows-rdp/)

The setup was successful, and I am able to access the machine remotely, however it will only work when there isn't a user currently logged in to the machine.

Alternatively, if I am accessing the machine remotely, then a local user is unable to log back into the same user account until the remote session logs out.

On Windows, I am used to seeing the user get kicked out if the remote or local user attempt to sign in to the same user account.

Does anyone have any advice on this, please?